# Selective url redirect using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a existing website with lots of images and static content. I have now signed up with MaxCDN and need to redirect the static content to their cdn.

I want to have a htaccess rule which will detect the file extensions like  `array('css', 'js', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' 'gif','pdf')` and redirect to the cdn url.

**Example**: 
Normal URL: https://www.example.com/uploads/slider/1470903158.jpg
CDN URL: https://www.cdn.com/uploads/slider/1470903158.jpg

I already have the CDN url for my zone defined. I would have done with the core`base_url()` override to perform the same function but unfortunately the website is not in CI and it wont be feasible to start over. I thought doing it with .htaccess will be my best bet in the current situation. Unfortunately i know next to nothing when it comes to .htacces.

This is my current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.?)index\.php/(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN Expires
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expires


#The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

    #The following line also enables compression by file content type, for the following list of Content-Type
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml

    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
   Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|pdf|css|js)$ https://www.cdn.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Please note that while this rule will work and perform exactly according to the question it wont solve the issue of CDN. A CDN will only catch content with http header 200 and not redirects(301). So even if you enabled this chances are depending on your CDN provider the site wont load or even if it loads it will defeat the purpose of a CDN since if all request go to your origin and then are redirected to the CDN datacenters there will be no increase in speed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but plz consider that not all static content would be under the `uploads/slider/` folder to basically I will need to remove the base url - `www.example.com` and replace it with the **CDN** base url and keep the rest of the url as it is

Comment: I added your rule but it is not redirecting neither is it giving any error. Have attached my existing .htaccess code is it possible this is interfering?

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.