# Javascript or PHP href string replace

Tags: javascript, php, string

If I have an HTML template like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/images/1.png">link text</a> 
<a href="/images/3.png">link text</a>
<a class="link" href="/images/4.png">link</a>
<img src="/img_4.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

How would I isolate and replace all `<a>` tag hrefs such that https://example.com prepends the relative urls but not absolute urls e.g I'd want the following result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css"> ***leave untouched absolute url not relative**
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://example.com/images/1.png">link text</a> **change**
<a href="https://example.com/images/3.png">link text</a> **change**
<a class="link" href="https://example.com/images/4.png">link</a> **change**
<img src="/img_4.jpg" />  ***leave untouched src not href**
</body>
</html>
```

I have a dilemma where I'm exploring ideas to prepend a CDN URL to certain file paths in a static HTML, CSS, JS website with thousands of files but I can't use htaccess (LAMP server) or base href (because of navigation). Manually adding links is also a non runner given the scale.
Reason I can't use htaccess: [Selective url redirect using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120321/selective-url-redirect-using-htaccess)
The CMS that generates the static website doesn't have the facility to prepend the CDN url in the file paths either.

Any recommendations greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: _"Manually adding links is also a non runner given the scale."_ [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) + [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) FTW.

Comment: Will investigate. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest solution would be by creating a $baseUrl variable.

In PHP:

```
$baseUrl = 'https://example.com';
```

Then in HTML you can do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/images/1.png">link text</a> 
<a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/images/3.png">link text</a>
<a class="link" href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/images/4.png">link</a>
<img src="/img_4.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Or in JavaScript you could do the following:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

Array.from(links).forEach(
    function(element, index) {
        var href = 'base_url' + element.getAttribute("href")
        element.setAttribute('href', href);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks but having to manually input <?php echo $baseUrl; ?> into thousands of html pages wouldn't be ideal. I appreciate the idea!

Comment: I edited the answer with a JavaScript example.

Answer (score 1):

As already proposed in the comments, you could use `sed` for that job in combination with `find`.

Bash example:

```
for file in `find . -name *.html`; do sed -E 's/href="\.?(\/[^"]*)"/href="https:\/\/example.com\1"/g' $file; done
```

By adding the `-i` option to the `sed` command, the files will be modified in-place. Use the above command without the `-i` option for testing purposes.

Input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/images/1.png">link text</a> 
    <a href="/images/3.png">link text</a>
    <a class="link" href="./images/4.png">link</a>
    <img src="/img_4.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://example.com/images/1.png">link text</a> 
    <a href="https://example.com/images/3.png">link text</a>
    <a class="link" href="https://example.com/images/4.png">link</a>
    <img src="/img_4.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks majusebetter